# How to use a pseudo-element to select links to domains ending in foo?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

[image]

I am taking practice test for Microsoft 70-480.  I came across the question in the image.  To select attributes that end in specific given value should be a css attribute selector such as [attribute$='value'].  I don't understand how we make that selection with a css pseudo-element.  Can some one explain to me why

Comment: only the person who said it's *correct* can tell you ... for me it's not correct,

Comment: There's no CSS pseudo element here. That's the element and what you are using is an attribute selector.

Comment: Thank you! I guess its just a flaw in that practice test

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly stated, you need an attribute selector for this (although you would need to use `[attribute*=value]` instead), and you can't match elements using pseudo-element selectors (that's why they're called *pseudo-elements*!).

The only explanation for the "correct answer" here being option C is that whoever wrote that test either made a mistake with the options, or doesn't understand CSS selectors. Hopefully the former.